# WPF Framework: Changing TextBlock Text in an Thread/Static function

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm a student who is currently trying to visualize some LED states from an Arduino UNO in an WPF.
And to check what kind of Data I get from the Arduino UNO I have created an TextBlock that should be Updated every time I recieve  Data.
Well, System.IO.Ports somewhat works, but I'm stuck at changing the TextBlocks Text, as you can not change a TextBlock in an Static function without proper preperations.
There is an Eventhandler for this so I wouldn't need Thread that handels the recieving Data, but it bothers me that I can't get it to work properly with an Static function aka inside an Thread.
Can you please HELP me to accomplish to change the Text property of an TextBlock inside an Static function?

I've tried to use Invoke functions: `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {...}):`, but I'm not certain how to use them and I tried to use `TextBlock textBlock = (TextBlock)Application.Current.FindResource("myTextBlock");` which didn't work ether.

Please don't lecture me to much, I'm trying to solve this for an week now, while I have to learn for my final exams and I'm sick of it.
But I would appreciate it if you would try to explain it to me how to do it properly <3.

C# Code that I liked to use:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Threading;

static public Thread readThread = new Thread(ThreadRead);

public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            readThread.Start();
        }

private static void ThreadRead()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                // New Text for the TextBlock-Object
                string message1 = "This is function";

                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    // Directly access the myTextBlock object
                    myTextBlock.Text = message1; // <------ This does not work
                });

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (TimeoutException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong");
            }
        }
    }
```

Xaml code that I'd like to use:

```
<Window x:Class="Read_Serial_Arduino.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Read_Serial_Arduino"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="137" Margin="310,90,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Hello World" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="421"/>
    </Grid>   
</Window>
```

Comment: Could you provide more code? Without the code, I can only say that you can try to pass a reference to the TextBlock into a thread, and then update it using Dispatcher. The second option is to use a messaging system.

Comment: I've totally forgotten the Dispacher. Well this would already solve it, sometimes simple things can also be usefull. 
I also updated my question and added code. 
But is there a way to edit the Text of an TextBlock inside a Static function?

Comment: No. Because your TextBlock is not static. If you need to access a non-static member, you need a reference to an instance. Passing one to that static method, you could do it _in_ a static method, but not _from_ a static method without ref to that instance.

Comment: But why don't you bind your ui component to a ViewModel, which gets updated by the event handler?